# How do I programmatically open a TSV file and save it as an XLSX file?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, export-to-excel

I would appreciate any pointers to documentation or API calls I can use.

Basically, I'm hoping there's some way to invoke Excel to make the conversion, although I haven't yet found any solutions that work for Excel 2010.

I am using the .NET framework.

Comment: Note that my use case is to make it easier for non tech-savvy users to use the output of my program.

Comment: Excel handles CSV files well and is the default editor for them on systems where the Excel install hasn't been customised.  I use csv files in almost all cases where I need an Excel file and I work with some very non tech-savvy users!  Converting a TSV to a CSV is trivial in comparison to converting to xlsx

Comment: I didn't realize Excel treated CSV's differently from TSV's. This solves my problem much more elegantly than my question originally requested.

Comment: I will accept this answer if it takes answer form, because it solves my actual problem, that of making it easy for users to view my data in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel handles CSV files well and is the default editor for them on systems where the Excel install hasn't been customised. I use csv files in almost all cases where I need an Excel file and I work with some very non tech-savvy users!

Converting a TSV to a CSV is trivial in comparison to converting to xlsx - one of the best libraries I have used for working with flat files is [Generic Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/GenericParser.aspx) which can read and write files delimited by any character (amongst many other things)

Answer (score 1):

I have used LINQ to CSV library in several projects to load and manipulate CSV,TSV,etc files.

- [LINQ to CSV library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx#How_to_use)

As for creating Office documents this is something that if you want easy conversion you will have to pay for. It is only really used in commercial applications so library writers know that there is a market for this.

That said there are some free libraries out there and I have heard good things about this one for editing Excel files:

- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: +1 This seems like a great library, thanks for sharing! Stack Overflow: try to answer somebody's question, learn something useful yourself instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lot of stuff like this using COM interop for Office. My recommendation is to check out the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx

It should  get you up and running with it. Let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: Does the application Excel actually have to be available on the machine where the converter will be deployed, or will the Interop DLL's be sufficient?

Comment: The actual application has to be present. If you want less bulky options they exist, but I can not vouch for their usability or stability. Check the top results: http://www.google.se/search?q=programmatically+create+excel+file

Comment: Microsoft [recommends against this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;257757) if you are planning on installing the interop in a server environment

Answer (score 0):

You can try the open source library [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to generate excel files. It's easier to deploy than the full Excel application.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try on [GroupDocs.Conversion REST API](https://forum.groupdocs.cloud/t/how-to-convert-tsv-to-xlsx-and-xlsx-to-tsv-with-groupdocs-conversion-rest-api/1239) for TSV to Excel or Excel to TSV conversion. You can use it via any REST Client or GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud SDK for .NET. Please note it is a paid API but its free plan offers free 150 API calls per month.

P.S:  I am developer evangelist at GroupDocs.

```
// Get Client Id and Client Key from https://dashboard.groupdocs.cloud/
var configuration = new GroupDocs.Conversion.Cloud.Sdk.Client.Configuration(ClientId, ClientKey);
var fileApi = new GroupDocs.Conversion.Cloud.Sdk.Api.FileApi(configuration);
var convertApi = new ConvertApi(configuration);

// Convert TSV to XLSX
var format = "xlsx";
var testFile = "C:/Temp/sample.tsv";

var request = new ConvertDocumentDirectRequest(format, File.OpenRead(testFile));
var result = convertApi.ConvertDocumentDirect(request);

// Save output to local drive
var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create("C:/Temp/sample.xlsx");
result.CopyTo(fileStream);
```